# How to add iOS simulators for Flutter in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm using the Flutter extension in vscode and can launch a test project on an ios simulator. But I have an iPad as the only option. How can I add other simulators, like an iPhone 11, to the list?

I found `flutter emulators --create`, but I don't find any info on using it and selecting the correct emulator. There is information available for Android devices, just not for ios.

I use Flutter 2.2.2 and have ios 9 as the target.

[image: devices selector]

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to launch your Simulator.app (the emulator on MacOS) and go to the `File` menu, then switch for another device !

[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks. Now iPhone appears in vscode as well.